# Does R ifelse work correctly with empty vectors?

Tags: r

I would expect `ifelse` function to return an empty vector of the same type as its second or third argument, as per the documentation:

> Value:
>
> A vector of the same length and attributes (including dimensions  and
>   ‘"class"’) as ‘test’ and data values from the values of ‘yes’  or
>   ‘no’.  The mode of the answer will be coerced from logical to 
>   accommodate first any values taken from ‘yes’ and then any values 
>   taken from ‘no’.

However it returns `logical(0)` in the case when all vectors are empty, regardless of the type of the second and third arguments (R version 3.3.2).

```
> ifelse(logical(), numeric(), numeric())
logical(0)
```

Is this a bug? If yes, how do I report it and is there any chance it is fixed?

My use case was my own function for replacing NAs with arbitrary values

```
rep_nan<-function(x, value=0) ifelse(is.na(x), value, x)
```

however the mentioned inconsistency causes type issues, for example, when working with `data.table`.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, `ifelse()` returns `logical(0)` not because the empty numeric is being coerced, but because whenever `test = logical(0)`, the result is `logical(0)`.

```
ifelse(logical(), numeric(), numeric())
# logical(0)

ifelse(0, numeric(), numeric())
# NA

ifelse(logical(), 0, 1)
# logical(0)
```

Even when returning a missing value, the coercion from logical happens as the documentation describes:

```
class(ifelse(0, numeric(), numeric()))
# "numeric"
```

Comment: I see the behaviour, and I now agree it may be interpreted to not contradict the documentation. But I still cannot see the reason for such behaviour.

Comment: @Valentas What would R return for an invalid logical test instead? It doesn't really make sense to return either of the `yes` or `no` parameter values, since `test` evaluates to neither false nor true. This behavior also mirrors `is.na(logical())` and is more informative than returning `NA` (i.e., it reports that the input was of length 0)

Comment: It should stop with exception with invalid logical test. I can just give an example where a corresponding function behaves properly and consistently: http://code.kx.com/q/ref/lists/#vector-conditional

Comment: @Valentas I don't know enough to judge whether this behavior is proper. I do think it is consistent, though, at least within R (as in my previous comment). And it also seems a bit much to ask that R *always* be consistent with another language.